# Keep java 6 along with newer java versions (for photoshop cs5)?

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop

I have adobe photoshop cs5 on a mac that was updated to yosemite. The yosemite update brought me to java v7. Trying to start photoshop now results in an error dialog telling me that photoshop needs java 6. There's a link in the error dialog about downloading the legacy version:

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US

is it possible to just install that legacy version and leave it side by side with the newer version 7? I don't want to install the legacy java6 version if it'll overwrite my v7 java install.

Thanks

Comment: You can have [multiple versions of Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252591/mac-os-x-and-multiple-java-versions). More information on switching between versions [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69086/how-can-i-switch-between-the-two-java-versions-in-mountain-lion-now-that-java-pr).